# i m making an app where i have to store my device id on db through an api. where i want to call the api only once the new device open the app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

my code is calling api every time coz it is declared under controller untill i dont check for the device id. but it if i save any device id then also it would call my service.

```
starticleApp.controller('deviceController', function($cordovaDevice,$http,$rootScope,$scope)
{
  if($rootScope.uuid != null)
  {
      var data = $.param({DeviceId:$rootScope.uuid});  
      result = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'http://temp1.techechelons.info/DesktopModules/Starticles/API/StarticlesService/SaveDeviceId',
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

    }).success(function(data)
      {   

       if(data.ResponseCode == 200)
        {
          //alert($scope.uuid);
          alert("device id received");
        }
        else 
        { 
       }
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: What you expect to do ?

Comment: @hav.narola Thanks for your revert although i figured it out to make it work only once with help of local storage

Comment: You are having problem with `if($rootScope.uuid != null)` ? Store UID in local storage and when controller is called at that time retrieve that UID form localstorage, if it gets localstorage then don't call API otherwise call API.

Comment: @hva.narola yes i have implemented it the same way but only difference is i did it in .run method() does it make any difference?

Comment: Try to console that locastorage value before checking condition to call API i.e above `if` statement.